# How to find the silenced pistol in Hotline Miami 1

Tags: hotline-miami

So I recently started achievement hunting hotline Miami and I have to use all the guns at least once. I've used every one except the silenced pistol and I can't find it anywhere! Is there a certain level it spawns on or something? Where can I find it?

Comment: It is very rarely found in the hands of enemies, as far as i know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Silenced Pistol is an unlockable sidearm found very rarely in the hands of enemies. It has a magazine size of 13 with a slow fire rate. The silencer stops enemies from hearing Jacket's shots and rushing to his location.

[Source](http://hotlinemiami.wikia.com/wiki/Silenced_Pistol)

> For some weapons to spawn, the player needs to unlock them first. Weapons can be unlocked by completing chapters. The score obtained from the chapter goes towards unlocking the next weapon. A new weapon is unlocked every 50,000 points until a total of 800,000 points is reached, upon which the final unlockable weapon is unlocked. Weapons are unlocked in the following order:
>
> Katana -> Glass Bottle -> Magnum -> Machete -> Beer Can -> Skorpion -> Hammer -> Brick -> Uzi -> Sledgehammer -> Ninja Star -> Dart -> MP5 -> Fireaxe -> Scissors -> Silenced Pistol

[Source](http://hotlinemiami.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons)

Hope that will help it's all I've found.

Comment: I've unlocked it so basically I just have to play until I find it?

Comment: seems like you've to